# Unity3D Math calculation issues

Tags: math, unity-game-engine

I'm not so skilled in the ways of math and retying to write the following formula.

```
40x^2 + 360x
```

Results are supposed to be as follows
x = 1 the result should be 400
x = 2 the result should be 900
x = 3 the result should be 1,600
x = 4 the result should be 2,100
x = 5 the result should be 2,800

```
result = 40 * (int)Mathf.Pow((float)x, 2f) + (360 * x)
```

x = 1 I get 400
x = 2 I get 880
x = 3 I get 1440
...etc

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Rather than using `Mathf.Pow()`, you should probably use `x*x` for x-squared... I would worry about floating-point precision/truncation problems from the floating point version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the answers you are getting from the code are the right ones.

As an example, in the top answers, where x = 2, 900 is not possible as an answer. Because; 360 * 2 = 720. To get 900, you need to add 180, which is not any multiple of 40, the nearest would be 160. Which adding that to 720 equals 880, such as in the answer from the code.

Comment: Thanks, I went a different route with what I needed. Instead of doing calculations I just created a Dictionary as a lookup.